# How to add a custom label title to <svg> content generated with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

In my project I got a feature where the user can generate some content in a `<textarea>`. I take that content and generate individual `<text>` elements from that content and display it in a `<svg>` so that the user can preview what they typed. [Here is a Codesandbox dispaying my problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-shadow-k18h6?file=/src/App.js).

When the user **starts typing**, I'd like to add a label **only once** (for example `Recipes`) to the preview. When the content in the `textarea` is cleared, I also would like for the label to be deleted.

How can I make it so that a label or title can be generated once to display above the user generated content?

***Code for Reference:***

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [dummyText, setDummyText] = useState("");

  const updateContent = (e) => {
    setDummyText(e.target.value);
  };

  function calculateWordWidths() {
    const words = dummyText.split(/\s+/);
    let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    let text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
    text.style =
      "font: 13pt LiberationSans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; white-space: pre;";
    svg.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(svg);

    const wordsWithComputedWidth = words.map((word) => {
      text.textContent = word;
      return { word, width: text.getComputedTextLength() };
    });

    text.textContent = "\u00A0"; // Unicode space
    const spaceWidth = text.getComputedTextLength();

    document.body.removeChild(svg);

    return { wordsWithComputedWidth, spaceWidth };
  }

  let { wordsWithComputedWidth, spaceWidth } = calculateWordWidths();

  const content = [[]];
  let xPos = 0;
  let yPos = 60;
  let page = 1;

  let i = 0,
    len = wordsWithComputedWidth.length;

  while (i < len) {
    if (yPos > 97) {
      content.push([]);
      page++;
      xPos = 0;
      yPos = 16;
    }

    //How do I add this label only once and automatically delete it once
    //the content in the text area is also deleted? Now it gets added
    //everytime a new letter is typed
    content[page - 1].push(
      <text
        x="0"
        y="24"
        key="1203"
        style={{
          font: "bold 17pt LiberationSans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
          whiteSpace: "pre"
        }}
      >
        Recipes
      </text>
    );

    //Push new text elements to the content array
    content[page - 1].push(
      <text
        x={xPos}
        y={yPos}
        key={i}
        style={{
          font: "13pt LiberationSans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
          whiteSpace: "pre"
        }}
      >
        {wordsWithComputedWidth[i].word}
      </text>
    );
    xPos += wordsWithComputedWidth[i].width + spaceWidth;
    if (xPos > 100) {
      yPos += 16;
      xPos = 0;
    }

    // console.log("xPos: ", xPos);
    // console.log("yPos: ", yPos);
    i++;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="content">
          <div>Content</div>
          <textarea
            rows="6"
            cols="24"
            onChange={(e) => updateContent(e)}
            style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="preview">
          <div>Preview</div>
          <>
            {content.map((resumePage, idx) => (
              <svg
                viewBox="0 0 595.28 100.89"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                style={{ border: "1px solid #aaa" }}
                key={idx}
              >
                {content[idx]}
              </svg>
            ))}
          </>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could conditionally push it into the array based on the `dummyText` state being populated.

```
!!dummyText && content[page - 1].push(
  <text
    x="0"
    y="24"
    key="1203"
    style={{
      font: "bold 17pt LiberationSans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
      whiteSpace: "pre"
    }}
  >
    Recipes
  </text>
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-add-a-custom-label-title-to-svg-content-generated-with-javascript]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this still adds the label 'Recipes' multiple times ( everytime dummyText is updated by the user by typing in the `<textarea>`). So I'm afraid this won't work... Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Reinier68 Can you clarify what you mean by "adds the label 'Recipes' multiple times"? I noticed no such duplication in your sandbox nor mine. Perhaps I'm not looking at the same thing you are. I assumed you were referring to the preview box where "Recipes" is displayed/rendered. Where is this label added more than once?

Comment: @Reinier68 Ok, I think I see what duplicates you are referring to, the `text` element with the "Recipes" text is pushed into the `content` array, with the same "1203" key. I don't understand the "paging" aspect of what you are rendering, and the UI doesn't reflect that AFAIK. Can you explain this part of your code? When do you want the "Recipes" text appended to the data? Does moving the above code ***outside*** the while loop resolve the duplication issue? See https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-add-a-custom-label-title-to-svg-content-generated-with-javascript-forked-pxlpd?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: Hi @Drew! Thanks alot for your example, this was exactly what I was looking for! The label 'Recipes' now only gets added once :). Thanks for helping me!